# Redirecting to another JSP page in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, button

```
                    <td><button name="button" value="OK" type="button" onclick="document.location.href='../JSP/DownloadReport.jsp';">Click Here</button>  </td>
```

I have a jsp page in folder D:\workspace\Report\WebContent\retrievedata.jsp in which i used button tag.
now from this button i want to redirect to page which is another folder D:\workspace\Report\WebContent\JSP\DownloadReport.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the more traditional way.

```
<a href="./JSP/DownloadReport.jsp">
   <button name="button" value="OK" type="button">Click Here</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `../` from your path i.e. you have to use the path as shown below:

```
<button name="button" value="OK" type="button" onclick="document.location.href='JSP/DownloadReport.jsp';">
```

It is because the path, `JSP/` is relative to the path of `retrievedata.jsp`.